# setting custom session in magento not works when caching is enabled

Tags: magento, caching

I have created a custom session in file of magento at bottom. For example:

```
 $_SESSION['testing']='testing';
```

and have checked on top that if session is set to 'testing' or not to check if user is visiting the site from cache or not. The code is working perfectly fine when cache is disabled.It gives empty value of session when loaded first time and gives 'testing' when loaded second time and so on.
But it is not working when I enable cache from backend, sometimes it unset the session every time I load page i.e. it gives value of `$_SESSION['testing']='testing'` every time I load the page. Is this a problem of  caching or something else is creating problem?

Comment: In `app/etc/local.xml` what is your config for node `<session_save>` ? files ? db ? memcache ?

Comment: it is <![CDATA[files]]> in local.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use magento way to set session :

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->setYourVariableName("your value here");
```

and retrieve like following :

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getYourVariableName();
```

For more detail you can look over following links

https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-set-retrieve-and-unset-session-variables-in-magento/

http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/anatomy-of-magento-session.html
Hope it helps :)

Comment: tried this too, but no luck this also is not working.

Comment: can you please show some code so that we can find some solution ?